# How do I display the infinity character/symbol in a textbox (any string really) in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, datagridview, character

How do I display this symbol as a character in a string (In my instance a datagridview textbox) using c#.NET? Is there even a unicode representation for infinity or am I out of luck and need to use an image?

[image]

Comment: This question can be answered with the Google searches "unicode representation for infinity" (taken directly from the question) and "c# unicode character".  If you looking to answer a deeper question, please modify the question to indicate the deeper question.

Comment: @erdomke I apologize for the admitted "simple" question, I tried to find resources and just came across a lot of stuff relating to C/C++ and numeric primitive infinities, not much (at least that I came across) in the vein of the infinity symbol representation

Comment: No need to apologize, and sorry if I came across as mean and "judgy".  Just trying to provide some ideas on other ways to figure this out (e.g. alternative search terms).  There are days that my Googling abilities fail me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just use the unicode syntax in C#

```
txt.Text = "\u221E";
```

See for example:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221e/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

Copy/paste from here or other locations on the Internet: ∞
I just did this in C# and it works.

`tbGreekChar.Text = "∞";`